# C++ how to print words with views::split?

Tags: c++, c++20

In [p0896r4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0896r4.pdf)

23.7.11.1 Overview [range.split.overview]

> 1. split_view takes a View and a delimiter, and splits the View into
>    subranges on the delimiter. The delimiter can be a single element or a
>    View of elements.

Example (with slight modification to compile)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <string>
    
int main()
{
    std::string str{"the quick brown fox"};
    std::ranges::split_view sentence{str, ' '};
    for (auto word : sentence) {
        for (char ch : word)
            std::cout << ch;
        std::cout << "*";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
the*quick*brown*fox*
```

However this is printing char by char, why can't I print a word instead?

```
for (auto word : sentence) 
    std::cout << word << std::endl;
```

Error: https://godbolt.org/z/GsPrhz

```
<source>:10:19: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'std::ranges::split_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::ranges::single_view<char> >::_OuterIter<true>::value_type')
```

Question: can I print the words? or does `std::ranges::single_view<char>` pose a contraint ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the standard views are printable, so the short answer is that you basically cannot. We're hoping to change this as part of [P2214](https://wg21.link/p2214).

`views::split` specifically has the issue that you can't even get a contiguous subrange out of it, so you can't meaningfully convert the pieces you get into `string_view`s either. This is [P2210](https://wg21.link/p2210).

The best solution I can offer today is to use the `fmt` library, which [lets you write](https://godbolt.org/z/8aefcd):

```cpp
char const* delim = "";
for (auto word : sentence) {
    fmt::print("{}{}", delim, fmt::join(word, ""));
    delim = " ";
}
```

I don't think `fmt` has any support for joining ranges of ranges, so I did the delimiting manually.

---

Note that `single_view<char>` is the pattern you're splitting on, not the piece you're getting back from `split`.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping something like `for (int i : ints | std::views::filter(even))` where I can print `i` is possible with split... One more thing, will [ranges::to](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1206r1.pdf) make into the standard? would be nice to have a function to convert any range to a container.

Comment: @TonyTannous Hope so.